# ack.pl tool and ack.pl flags

Tags: linux, filesystems, grep, perl, ack

I am using the ack.pl tool in order to search string or IP’s in files

The official site of ack.pl is - http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/

Example of ack.pl CLI ( want to find the string STRING_TO_FIND in files under /etc )

```
  /tmp/ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1  STRING_TO_FIND  /etc
```

But sometimes ack.pl is stuck on files as:

```
  ---S--l---   1 root     root          0 Mar 10 04:25  /opt/POP_lock
```

From MAN paget "S" attr mean that:

Using an upper-case "S" instead of a lower-case "s" tells the filesystem to immediately write the file to disk, instead of storing it in a buffer. (Note also, that we left the "s" attribute this time, so that we now have two attributes set for this file.)

So my question is:

How ack.pl can ignore the files with “S” , 
Or what the ack.pl flags that shuld ignore this files with “S” ?

Comment: Consider adding [tag:ack] to your list of tags

Comment: I add the ack.pl in the flags

Comment: What man page are you quoting as saying that an upper-case “S” instead of a lower-case “s” tells the filesystem to immediately write the file to disk, instead of storing it in a buffer?  I was about to refer you to the question [File with permissions `---S--l---`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189240/23408) until I saw that you wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it’s the “`S`” that’s causing the problem? 
As I explained in my answer to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189240/23408), the “`l`” signifies that
your operating system and filesystem support mandatory file locking,
and mandatory file locking is enabled for this file. 
I doubt that it’s a coincidence that both files you give as examples
(in this question and the previous one) have names that end with `_lock`. 
These files are probably — guess what? — ***locked!*** 
This could prevent `ack` (or any other program) from reading them.
*(The above is the answer to the question, “Why can’t `ack` read these files?”,
which, I realize, you didn’t ask.)*

Search for all files that have the “`l`” mode bit set using the

```
find /etc -perm -2000 ! -perm -010
```

command (which I presented in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189256/23408) to your previous question). 
See whether all the files have names that end with `_lock`.  Then do

```
find /etc -name "*_lock" –ls
```

to verify that all `_lock` files have the “`l`” mode bit set. 
If there is a one-to-one correspondence
(or, in general, if there are no `_lock` files that you need to search),
exclude them from your search by filename pattern.

I don’t have access to a copy of `ack` to test with, but,
from the documentation,
it looks like you may be able to do this with `--ignore-file="match:/.*_lock/"`,
or something like that.